How to prevent water from pooling at back door when it rains
I have an uncovered, concrete patio and front porch, and spent who knows how long researching and testing out different outdoor mats. I live in Va, so I get everything from blazing sun to downpours to snow, and with an uncovered porch, finding mats that can stand up to the elements is not easy. I finally tried the mats made out of nautical rope that’s woven together (so basically all-weather proof) and love that they actually drain vs collect water when it rains. BUT now I’ve discovered a new problem: when the water drains through the mat it is draining at a slope towards the door. More specifically, it’s going under the lip of the door where there’s about a 1-2in gap, and pooling against the siding. It’s not the door mat that’s the issue now, it’s the actual patio. My question is, has anyone had this issue and what did you do? I’m no able to hire someone to build up the concrete and level it out, so I’m looking for possible short-term solutions on the cheap. I thought about putting some kind of weather stripping or rubber along the gap between the concrete patio and lip of the door frame to stop water damaging the side of the house, or trying to prop the door mat up with something so it’s at an angle (although I’d have to get yet another mat that’s not woven so water runs off it away from door vs draining straight through it). My concern is the potential water damage that’s being done to wood around the frame of the door- which is already visible- and to the side of house that runs under the back door. Sorry for the novel! Thanks for any suggestions in advance!!

Can you provide some photos that include the location in question, plus the entire patio?

Re-grade the property so the ground near the back door slopes away frome the house. You'll reduce the risk of basement leaks too.
